# Laravel 5.5 use of env string in route name screws Route::has()

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

For absolute testing purpose  (it's probably not a consistent behaviour I'll keep on my code) I try to use a custom admin pannel route set with the .env file (As it seemed relevant in securing the whole thing, but not so sure anymore).

As I want that people visiting the site can see that admin pannel in guest mode, I thought it would be cool to set a rerouting middleware that simply put a guest after that .env set admin route. Guests who try to get to /admin/jobs would end on /admin/guest/jobs with lowered permission controller.

The code below works fine without the .env thingy.

It's set like this in \Route\web.php

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    $adminRoute = config('app.admin-route');
    $adminRoute = (preg_match('/[\/].*/', $adminRoute)) ? $adminRoute : '/' . $adminRoute;

    Route::middleware('isadmin')->group(function () use ($adminRoute) {
        Route::get($adminRoute, 'AdminController@index')->name('adminPanel');
        Route::get($adminRoute . '/test', function () {
            echo 'test';
        });
    });
    Route::get($adminRoute . '/guest/{where?}', 'AdminController@guest')->where('where', '.*')->name('adminAsGuest');
});
```

And the corresponding isAdmin middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $adminRoute = config('app.admin-route');
    $adminRoute = (preg_match('/\/.*/', $adminRoute)) ? $adminRoute : '/' . $adminRoute;
    // check if authentified
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        // check if admin
        if (Auth::user()->role == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            $route = "/".$request->route()->uri;
            // check if route exists
            if (Route::has($route)) {
                // trim the route after admin and puts a guest inside
                $redirect = preg_replace("/\\".$adminRoute."/", "", $route);
                return redirect($adminRoute . '\/guest/' . $redirect);
            }
            else {
                // if it doesn't, let it go to the laravel error
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

    }

    // if auth middleware was used on same route, won't go there anyways
    // if not, redirect to root route
    return redirect('/');
}
```

I'm on a struggle there as `Route::has($route)` doesn't trigger correctly as long as I use env("APP_ADMIN_ROUTE") as the root of the admin routes.

Here's my debugging outputs just before `if (Route::has($route))`

```
Auth::check()
    true
Auth::user()->role
    0
$route
    "/admin/test"
Route::has($route);
    false


vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/var/www/html$ wphp artisan route:list
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware       |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                      |                  | App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController@index                           | web              |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin                  | adminPanel       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@index                       | web,auth,isadmin |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/guest/{where?}   | adminAsGuest     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@guest                       | web,auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/test             |                  | Closure                                                                | web,auth,isadmin |
```

I know it would certainly be more consistent to go for admin controllers in which I constantly track the role of the user connected, and give there or not the right to modify things. But I'm really curious to know if there's any possible way to work it like I tried here.

I've seen [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) and it would certainly work great on a simplier approach, and it's my next step if there's no positive answer to my current issue :)

Here's my first question on StackOverflow. I used great search for that precise thing without success. I apologize if I missed an obvious answer somewhere.

Edit: Updated the code after Joel Hinz's comment.

```
// \Config\app.php
'admin-route' => env('APP_ADMIN_ROUTE', 'admin'),
```

Comment: Oh, I'm confused now. That was working yesterday without the env thing, so I reversed it and I'm not able to make it work again. It seems like Route::has() works with route names and not URI. I'll investigate this way and check with that https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/check-if-route-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first question, first anwer, looks like I didn't explore all possibilities.

The issue wasn't using variables in route URI definition, but an improper use of `Route::has()`. This works only with route names, and not route URI. Proper way to check if a route exists, according to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/check-if-route-exists is to use a `Route::checkRoutes->match($testValue)` with a `$testValue` member of Illuminate\Http\Request.

`Route::checkRoutes->match($testValue)` will return a Illuminate\Routing\Route instance with the first match, and an empty value if there's no match.

In a middleware handle() context it can articulates like this:

```
$route = "/" . $request->route()->uri;
// Shape your test route URI in a request
$testValue = $request->create($route);
// check if route exists
if (Route::getRoutes()->match($testValue)) {
    // statements here
}
```

So, the correct middleware complete code is:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $adminRoute = config('app.admin-route');
    $adminRoute = (preg_match('/\/.*/', $adminRoute)) ? $adminRoute : '/' . $adminRoute;
    // check if authentified
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        // check if admin
        if (Auth::user()->role == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            $route = "/" . $request->route()->uri;
            $nreq = $request->create($route);
            // check if route exists
            if (Route::getRoutes()->match($nreq)) {
                // trim the route after admin and puts a guest inside
                $redirect = preg_replace("/\\".$adminRoute."/", "", $route);
                return redirect($adminRoute.'/guest' . $redirect);
            }
            else {
                // if it doesn't, let it go to the laravel error
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

    }

    // if auth middleware was used on same route, won't go there anyways
    // if not, redirect to root route
    return redirect('/');
}
```

What leads me in the way of thinking this is only useless code block as the middleware will only trigger on an existing /admin/something route URI, and testing if route exists there makes no point.

Well, anyways, thanks to everyone who took time to read that, see you around.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to let the config files read the .env variables, and then load the settings from the config files where you actually need them. That way, they can be cached, and you virtually always know that they've already been read properly instead of having to wonder where they'll work and where they won't.

In your case, just something like this should be enough:

```
// in .env
APP_ADMIN_ROUTE=something

// in e.g. config/app.php
'admin-route' => env('APP_ADMIN_ROUTE');

// in the middleware
$adminRoute = config('app.admin-route');
```

I'm not 100 % sure this is actually your issue, but it's worth a shot - and even if it doesn't work, it's still a best practice. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Joel. I changed accordingly, and will use that from now on. Unfortunately it didn't correct the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Hope somebody else has the right answer then!